# use Graphics (for ex) methods without prefixing an instance variable

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, haxe

I'm new to AS3 and Haxe, but was hoping to find a way to use methods from a final class (Graphics) without always prefixing an instance variable.

Instead of something like this:

```
var gr:Graphics = flash.Lib.current.graphics;

gr.clear();
gr.beginFill(0xffffff, 1);
gr.drawRect(0,0,400,400);
```

I was hoping to get something that works like processing.org, but I guess a lot of the convenience there comes from the preprocessing. I looked at the Haxe reference on [advanced types](http://old.haxe.org/ref/type_advanced), but I haven't been able to make anything work so far. This probably isn't possible since Graphics is final, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to ask. It seems it would be easy if I could extend Graphics. Anyway, thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's the code for implementing a very simple `with() {...}` emulation on Haxe:

```
//simple.hx
class Simple 
{

    @:macro public static function with(subject:Expr, block:Expr)
    {
        return with_impl(subject, block);
    }

    #if macro
    static function with_impl(subject:Expr, block:Expr)
    {
        function mk(e, pos) return { expr:e, pos:pos };

        //this is the main function here. It's going to find a variable  the expression so it uses our subject
        function changeIdent(identExpr:Expr, changeExpr)
        {
            return switch(identExpr.expr)
            {
                case EConst(c):
                switch(c)
                {
                    case CIdent(s):
                    mk(EField(changeExpr, s), identExpr.pos);

                    default:
                    identExpr;
                }

                case EField(e, f):
                mk(EField(changeIdent(e, changeExpr), f), identExpr.pos);

                case EType(e, f):
                mk(EType(changeIdent(e, changeExpr), f), identExpr.pos);

                default: //fallba
                identExpr;
            }
        }

        return switch(block.expr)
        {
            case EBlock(exprs):
            var newblock = [];
            for (statement in exprs)
            {
                switch(statement.expr)
                {
                    case ECall(e, params):
                    newblock.push(mk(ECall(changeIdent(e, subject), params), statement.pos));
                    default:
                    newblock.push(statement);
                }
            }

            mk(EBlock(newblock), block.pos);

            case EDisplay(e, iscall):
            mk(EDisplay(with_impl(subject, e), iscall), block.pos);

            default:
            changeIdent(block, subject);
        }
    }
    #end
}
```

you use it like this:

```
//Main.hx
class Main 
{

    static function main() 
    {
        Simple.with (Lib.current.graphics,
        {
            beginFill(0xC0FFEE, 1);
            drawRect( -10, -10, 20, 20 );
            endFill();
        });
    }

}
```

Instead of changing the scope, it will look for call expressions and just add the first argument of the function (subject) to be in every expression. So the code above is equivalent to:

```
{
    Lib.current.graphics.beginFill(0xC0FFEE, 1);
    Lib.current.graphics.drawRect( -10, -10, 20, 20 );
    Lib.current.graphics.endFill();
}
```

macros are so fun!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! This looks really good. I'm sure there are other people who would like to have this available in HaXe too. I'll have to try to understand the macro when I try it later today.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem with the "using" example was that it had to be used inside a seperate instance of (or inheriting from) Sprite for each class (since there are no inner classes in HaXe). This method allows multiple classes to use one Graphics instance which is what I was looking for although I don't think I specified that detail in the original question (sorry).

Answer (score 1):

Use can try [using mixin](http://haxe.org/manual/using).

For example create a class GraphicHelper:

```
class GraphicHelper {
    inline public static function drawRect(sp:Sprite, x:Float, y:Float, w:Float, h:Float) {
        sp.graphics.drawRect(x,y,w,h);
    }
}
```

And then in your Sprite class:

```
using GraphicHelper;

class Square extends flash.display.Sprite {
    public function new():Void {
        super();
        drawRect(0,0,10,10); //this is GraphicHelper.drawRect(this,0,0,10,10); and since it is inline, actually is this.graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It works okay, but its kind of a pain to wrap all the methods. I'll probably end up using this.

Answer (score 1):

Does using the 'with' keyword help any?

```
var someSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
with( someSprite.graphics )
{
    beginFill(0xC0FFEE, 1);
    drawRect( -10, -10, 20, 20 );
    endFill();
}
```

Comment: That is really nice. I was very disappointed to see that HaXe doesn't support this.[link](http://haxe.org/doc/start/flash/as3migration/part1)

Comment: @Waneck I tried to figure out how I would do that for quite a while, but was unsuccessful. I think macros are a little over my head as a HaXe beginner.

Comment: @user the main point you have to figure out is the main problem with with() syntax: how to deal with scope issues. the idea is pretty simple, I'll find some time to write a snippet for you